# Expected Expression before ":" token

Tags: iphone

I am getting this error in first two lines of code given below

and the error is "Expected Expression before ":" token"....

some one please help me to overwrite this....

```
(IBAction)buttonPressed {
    NSInteger stateRow =[picker selectedRowInComponent:kStateComponent];
    NSInteger zipRow =  [picker selectedRowInComponent:kZipComponent];
    NSString *state=[self.states objectAtIndex:stateRow];
    NSString *zip=[self.zips objectAtIndex:zipRow]
    NSString *title=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"You selected zip code %@",zip];
    NSString *message=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ is in %@",zip,state];
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [title release];
    [message release];

}
```

Comment: @Ammu :What is the value of kStateComponent ?

Comment: Are you sure, your program knows about kStateComponent?

Comment: yes my program knows about that

Comment: @Ammu:-1 for you. Not good to ignore real quick answerers and to respond to an answer which has been copied. This will put a bad impression of yours on regular and sincere answerers in StackOverflow. So keep in mind that time is also an important factor. Anyways this is just my suggestion. Afterall whats your impression on others depends on you.

Comment: @ Julia .... I dont understand what your talking about ?

Answer (score 4):

You have to write it as

```
(IBAction)buttonPressed {
```

Infact it should be

```
 -(IBAction)buttonPressed {
```

May be `-` is missing that might be creating this error.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

If still it doesnt help, then you may try this.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
```

**EDIT-2:**

Also you are missing a `;` at the end of statement no 4

that is

```
 NSString *zip=[self.zips objectAtIndex:zipRow]
```

You should add a semicolon(;) there at the end

Hope this solves it

Comment: @Ammu: even the semicolon is there?

Comment: @Ammu: Seems there is some problem in other part of your code which is showing the error over this code.

Answer (score 3):

There's a **-** missing right at the beginning before (IBACTION).

Comment: @Eiko: As you are a well reputed member on StackOverflow you might be knowing that there is no point putting duplicate answers right? Nothing Personal.

Comment: @PARTH Seems identical - it was posted the same time (no idea which one got through first). Definitely didn't see yours before posting.

Comment: Yeah.. My time is 06:48:24Z and Yours is 06:48:50Z Anyways. :)

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. I am glad that I do my bit in helping others :)

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define kStateComponent 0 ;
#define kZipComponent 1;

@interface DependentComponentPickerViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource> {
 IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
 NSDictionary *stateZips;
 NSArray *states;
 NSArray *zips;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)UIPickerView *picker;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSDictionary *stateZips;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *states;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *zips;
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
see this is my .h file

Comment: And this is my .m file#import "DependentComponentPickerViewController.h"
//#define kStateComponent 0;
//#define kZipComponent 1;


@implementation DependentComponentPickerViewController
@synthesize picker;
@synthesize stateZips;
@synthesize states;
@synthesize zips;

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSString *plistPath=[bundle pathForResource:@"statedictionary" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSDictionary *dictionary=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
 self.stateZips=dictionary;
 [dictionary release];
 NSArray *components=[self.stateZips allKeys];
 NSArray *sorted=[components sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
 self.states=sorted;
 NSString *selectedState=[self.states objectAtIndex:0];
 NSArray *array=[stateZips objectForKey:selectedState];
 self.zips=array;
 
}

Comment: -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
NSInteger stateRow =[picker selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)Component];
NSInteger zipRow =  [picker selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)Component];
NSString *state=[self.states objectAtIndex:stateRow];
NSString *zip=[self.zips objectAtIndex:zipRow];
NSString *title=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"You selected zip code %@",zip];

Comment: #pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker Data Source Methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)PickerView{
 return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
 if(component == kStateComponent)
  return[self.states count];
 
 return[self.zips count];
}

Comment: #pragma mark Picker Delegate methods

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
 if(component == kStateComponent)
  return[self.states objectAtIndex:row];
 
  return[self.zips objectAtIndex:row];
 
}

Comment: - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
 if(component == kStateComponent){
 
  NSString *selectedState=[self.states objectAtIndex:row];
  NSArray *array=[stateZips objectForKey:selectedState];
  self.zips=array;
  [picker selectRow:0 inComponent:kZipComponent animated:YES];
  [picker reloadComponent:kZipComponent];
  
 }
}
@end

Comment: @Ammu: You could have better edited your question and posted this code in your question itself as it is unreadable here.

Comment: Hi perth i got resolved it for buddy thabk you for responding quickly:)

Comment: yes that is good parth ... in the header file i placed semicolon at the end of the define component that  is the main mistake it seems see  like this #define kStateComponent;and #define kZipComponent; i shouldn't place semicolon at the end of the define component.... that was my mistake ... is it clear parth?

Comment: Man, please stop posting code in comments. And semicolon in #define constants doesn't make sense at all. It is just a text substitution.

Answer (score -1):

I have tested this code and its working properly.

change the "(NSInteger)component" as per requirement of picker.

- (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender {

```
NSInteger stateRow =[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:"(NSInteger)component"];
NSInteger zipRow =  [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:"(NSInteger)component"];

NSLog(@"stateRow - %d",stateRow);
NSLog(@"zipRow - %d",zipRow);
```

}

And also put - (IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender; in **.h** file

Comment: @Chetan : **Dont** Post Duplicate answers. Cant you see two answer already on same lines?

Comment: hey now it is showing different error like this Expected "]"before ":" token

Comment: Hey Ammu you use this code? pass the nsinteger value instead of string.

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define kStateComponent 0 ;
#define kZipComponent 1;

@interface DependentComponentPickerViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource> {
 IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
 NSDictionary *stateZips;
 NSArray *states;
 NSArray *zips;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)UIPickerView *picker;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSDictionary *stateZips;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *states;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *zips;
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
@end

Comment: hey chetan check it now i gave my full code and thank you for ur good response buddy

Comment: Duplicate answers are not the way to go ahead in SO. Create your own answers. If your answer resembles with some existing answer then you should either upvote(only if you want) and if you want to edit the answer and add some more data to it, then you can do that too. You need to read some FAQ's on Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: hey chetan i got resolved this error and thank you for responding very quickly:)

Comment: @chetan: -1 for copying. I would have given you -10 if I could.  Huh..!! This is sheer cheating by you...!! Stop being a Looser and copying others answers..!!